# Why do terminal buffers get deleted in Neovim

Tags: neovim, terminal-buffer

My terminal buffers get deleted automatically when I switch to a different buffer. Is that supposed to happen? It's really annoying. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be related to a [known bug](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3340) involving not listing the terminal buffer at times. This prevents the problem `set hidden`. It is currently (March 2016) planned to fix this in the upcoming 0.2 release.